# I have the number of days (stored in SQL db as 37867) since 1900 and want to convert it to a date like "Sep-5-2003

Tags: c#

I have a number retrieved from SQL = 37867 and need to convert it to the date it represents which is 2003-09-05.
The number 37867 represents the number of days since 1900 and the answer should be 2003-09-05 but how to calculate this in C#?

This is the SQL function that does it: "SELECT CONVERT(datetime,37867)" but how can I do it in C# so I can update that int and make it a string literal and replace that int with that string?

I am guessing that this is how the struct for Windows stores the DateTime stamp.

If I spend enough time I am pretty sure I can figure it out, but it will take more time than I really want to spend and if someone else already has...why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(37867);` Just replace the int literal with your variable from SQL.

Comment: Down vote for not trying

Comment: @DerrickMoeller's answer is correct.  You are _"guessing that this is how the struct for Windows stores the DateTime stamp"_.  A `DateTime` includes both the date and the time.  The `AddDays` method allows you to do what you want to do.  More generally, you can use a `TimeSpan` to adjust a `DateTime`.  So you can get 6 hours from now by adding `DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(6)`.  Dates and times are tricky (ask anyone who lives near the International Date Line).  You should familiarize yourself with both DateTime and TimeSpan if you are doing any time/date calculations.

Comment: This article of mine -- coincidentally from September 2003 -- might be of interest to you. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/

Comment: Your final paragraph basically says "wasting the time of people on stackoverflow is better than me doing any research".  Though this attitude is certainly popular around here, you'll find it is not very endearing. **Please do basic research before you ask a question**.

Comment: That worked Perfect. Thank You Rufus. And for Eric, I worked on it for 2 days and was basically trying to reverse engineer the difference between two dates. Was going down the wrong road. Sorry for my stupidity but please don't ASSUME I did not do any research. You know what happens when you assume.

Comment: Are you saying that in 2 days you didn't once look at the type definition?

Answer (score 1):

This community generally prefers that you make an attempt, if we see what you were attempting to do it's generally easier to help then writing something from scratch.

Having said that:

```
// Create new DateTime, January 1st 1900
var dt = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

// Add 37867 days to that DateTime
dt = dt.AddDays(37867);

// Call ToString()
var s = dt.ToString();
```